# possible delete candidate: "algebras" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is a tag titled [algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebras). It has only been used on one single question (and another one used it recently, but I replaced it with a more appropriate tag). Is it necessary, or should it be deleted?

Comment: Looks like an invitation to put C*-algebras, commutative algebras and Lie algebras in one place. What a horrible tag.

Comment: If there's only one question that uses this tag, we needn't bother "deleting" anything.  We can just change that single instance (if desired).  But I wouldn't do anything before hearing from [@Mariano Suárez-Alvarez](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/274/mariano-suarez-alvarez) who is the author of the question.

Comment: I'll add link to an [older discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2524407#2524407) about tagging questions concerning *[algebras over a field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)*. It seems that we do not have a tag specifically for this type of algebras.